# How to connect to Heroku Postgresql from Sails.js Java Script

Tags: javascript, postgresql, heroku, sails.js

js to create my application. I want to use Heroku database hosting where I created and got database. Now i try to connect to it from my application. That's snippet from my local.js :

```
adapters: {

'default': 'postgres',
 module   : 'sails-postgresql',
 host     : '...',
 port     : 5432,
 user     : '...',
 password : '...',
 database : '...',

 schema: true //This makes sure that sails matches 
               //the database schema to your models.
}
```

When i lift the sails application i got error :

"Error creating a connection to Postgresql: error: no pg_hba_conf entry for host "83.21...", user ..., database ..., SSL off"

The "..." are user,databse etc from my local.js.

How to fix the problem? When I change the data in the local.js to my local postgresql database it works fine, but when I change the data and try to connect to the database on Heroku hosting it displays the error all time :/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Heroku requires the ssl setting to be turned on. Add ssl: true to your config like so:

```
module   : 'sails-postgresql',
host     : '...',
port     : 5432,
user     : '...',
password : '...',
database : '...',
ssl      : true
```